# checking if all values of a hash are correct values (from a predefined value set) in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash table with multiple values being passed to a function I dont know the names of the keys but i know that the values of the keys must be equal to characters A S or X.
How can i easily check that all values in the hash table are equal to those characters?

Comment: I don't know ruby, but it would seem like this should work: [`hash.values.all? {|s| (s =~ /^[ASX]$/) != nil }`](http://codepad.org/P9Bsv3Vd) See: [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NullUserException is good, you could also

```
match_values = %w(A S X)
hash.values.all? { |value| match_values.include?(value) }
```